# Swift/SpriteKit: Animate multiple buttons with small delay between each

Tags: swift

I have several buttons (SKSpriteNodes) which I am trying to cycle through and animate, with a small delay between each. My code compiles, but when I run it - I only get a white screen and a crash with this error: "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue". Here is my code:

```
var sequence = SKAction.sequence([animationUp, animationDown])

runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([

    SKAction.runBlock({

        button1.runAction(sequence)
        SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)

        button2.runAction(sequence)
        SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)

        button3.runAction(sequence)
        SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)

    }),

])))
```

So what I am trying to accomplish is an up/down animation on every button I'm drawing to the screen, with a 0.5 second delay between each button. The animation should run forever until I change the current screen. I had no problem animating these buttons simultaneously but I'd really like to add a uniform delay so that they don't all animate at the same time. Any ideas?

Comment: The way you use SKAction sequence is completely wrong. Do you realize that you are repeating a block forever ? The action to be repeated must have a non-instantaneous duration. According to the docs, SKAction.runBlock has instantaneous effect. This is the same as while(1){do something}

Comment: Well, this isn't how I was _using_ my SKAction sequence, this is just what I was trying to do but wasn't able to figure out, hence posting my question in the first place.

Comment: Well, you complained about memory problems. Repeating that block of code forever was the cause. About accepted answer...It might work for you, but depending on how buttons are declared (local variables or as properties) you might run into strong reference cycle issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
let movementAction = SKAction.sequence([animateUp, animateDown])
let button1Block = SKAction.runBlock({
   button1.runAction(movementAction)
})
let button2Block = SKAction.runBlock({
   button2.runAction(movementAction)
})
let button3Block = SKAction.runBlock({
   button3.runAction(movementAction)
})
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([button1Block,waitAction,button2Block, waitAction, button3Block, waitAction])
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence))
```

Comment: Nice clean solution, thanks a lot. Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about how the SKAction.sequence initiates/destroys, but possibly your loop in .repeatActionForever(..) creates and destroys objects, whereas memory won't be released until the loop is allowed to complete.

Try to run your inner runAction block within an autoreleasepool { .. } block:

```
autoreleasepool {
    runAction ... 
}
```

> But there is one situation we do need to autorelease, that is we
>   create a lot of objects in a method scope and want to release them
>   sooner. It is extremely useful when these objects turn to a pressure
>   on memory.

http://en.swifter.tips/autoreleasepool/